# $f$ an entire function, $|f(1/n)|\leq n^{-n}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $f$ is constant.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working on old qualifying exam problems and this one came up.

Suppose $f$ is an entire function on $\mathbb{C}$, and that $|f(\frac{1}{n})| \leq n^{-n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$. Prove that $f$ is constant.

My approaches: One obvious thing to do is to try and show that $f$ is bounded and appeal to Liouville's theorem. However, our bounds are for small values of $z$, so this did not yield much success.

One can see that $f(0)=0$ from this condition. Also,
$$
 f'(0) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(\frac{1}{n}) - f(0)}{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} n f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
$$
Note that
$$
 \left|nf\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right| \leq n^{-n+1} \to 0 \text{ as } n\to \infty.
$$
Thus, $f'(0)=0$.

I would like to keep trying to show that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ and use the fact that $f$ is entire to get that $f=0$ identically on $\mathbb{C}$. But I get stuck because I don't have an estimate for $f'(1/n)$.

I think what makes this problem harder is that we only have an estimate on $f$ at a countable set, instead of the usual problem where we know some kind of bound on $f$ everywhere.

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Try to use the maximum principle on the unit disk and then use the identity principle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f$ is not identically zero then $f$ has a zero of multiplicity $k \ge 0$ at $z=0$, i.e.
$$
f(z) = z^k g(z)
$$
where $g$ is an entire function with $g(0) \ne 0$.

Then $$
\bigl|g(\frac 1n)\bigr| = n^k \, \bigl|f(\frac 1n)\bigr| \le \frac{n^k}{n^n}
$$
for all positive integers $n$. The right-hand side tends to zero for $n \to \infty$
and it follows that $g(0) = 0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I like this approach, but shouldn't it read $n^k/n^n $ in the last inequality?

Comment: @Andrew: You are right of course, that was a stupid error. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinR,How do you know that $f$ has a zero at z=0???Please explain it.

Comment: @Kilimanjaro: It follows from the given estimate $|f(\frac{1}{n})| \leq n^{-n}$. But actually you don't need that, $k=0$ is an allowed value in the proof.

Comment: @MartinR,but why?I mean we could have a zero at say,$z=1/2$ or so.

Comment: @MartinR,Ok ,now I got it so by letting $n$ tend to $\infty$ ,you get $z=0$ is a zero.Don't you?

Comment: @Kilimanjaro: I did nowhere say that $z=0$ is the *only* zero of $f$.

Comment: @Kilimanjaro: By allowing $k=0$ this first step (showing that $f(0)=0$) is not needed. It makes the proof a tiny bit shorter, that's all.

Comment: @MartinR,now I got it.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is entire, we know
$$f(z) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j z^j \quad \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$$
Using the bound given, we see
$$ \left |f\left (\frac{1}{n}  \right) \right | = \left | \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{a_j}{n^j}  \right | \leq \frac{1}{n^n}$$
You've already seen that $a_0=0$ by taking $n\to \infty$, now pull out a factor of $n$ to see
$$\left |f\left (\frac{1}{n}  \right) \right | = \frac{1}{n}\left | \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{a_j}{n^{j-1}}  \right | \leq \frac{1}{n^n}\implies  \left|n f\left ( \frac{1}{n} \right) \right | =\left | \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{a_j}{n^{j-1}}  \right | \leq \frac{1}{n^{n-1}}$$
i.e. we have that $a_i =0$ for $i \in [0,n]$. Proceed with induction to conclude such a function is identically zero.

Remark to what you said: You don't need to have the estimate on $f'(1/n)$ since the function is entire and your representation holds for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I don't see how you arrive at the conclusion that $a_i=0$ for $i\in [0,n)$.

Comment: you iterate the bound and take the limit, i.e.$$|n^2 f(1/n) | \leq \frac{1}{n^{n-2}} \implies a_2 \leq 0 \ldots| n^{n-1}f( 1/ n) | \leq \frac{1}{n} \implies a_{n-1} = 0 $$